How to Create a Popup Window in Unity UI Toolkit for Runtime?
I’m working with Unity’s UI Toolkit and trying to implement a popup window that appears when clicking a menu button. The expected behavior is that when I click the menu button, a popup window with some options should appear below the button. However, I’ve noticed that the PopupWindow class is part of the Unity Editor API and isn’t available for runtime builds.
My Questions:

Does Unity UI Toolkit provide a built-in way to create popup windows at runtime?'

If not, what’s the recommended approach for building a popup window from scratch using UI Toolkit?


Any examples, advice, or best practices would be appreciated! Thank you.
